# Overpass Python module query for a way, returns valid response but empty LineString coordinates field

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I use the following query with Overpass Python module, for getting the features of a road in overpass turbo:

```
[out:json]
[timeout:25]
;
(
  node["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
  way["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
  relation["name"="John F Foran Freeway"];
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The response contains a valid array of points and lines, but when I look inside the LineString objects the coordinates field is empty.

The geometry coordinates for the points are correct.

Any idea about this behaviour?

Comment: Side note: you're running a global query, without any restriction to a bounding box. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: Anyone having this issue please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584423/overpass-api-ways-query-include-coordinates

Comment: @mmd Yes you are right:)